# SSL Verification Failed in AWS Lambda using Python 3.8

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ssl, aws-lambda, pyopenssl

I have migrated my Python flask app to AWS Lambda after which I started getting the following error of

`SSL Verification Failed`

Currently using AWS CDK to upload the lambda package and deploying it.

```
python 3.8 ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1131)
```

And this is happening on `api.pagerduty.com`

My *requirements.txt* file includes **PyOpenSSL** and **Certifi** packages, tried different APIs all of them are failing because of SSL verification using **requests** package's `post` method

Already know about `verify=False` attribute but want to fix the problem as to why its happening.

Let me know if you guys need any more details around it, really Appreciate it.

Comment: Edit: I have tried adding OpenSSL Lambda layer from here https://github.com/alexandredavi/openssl-lambda-layer but still getting the same error.

Comment: Just to confirm, did you package your dependencies in Linux? Since PyOpenSSL seems to be referring to some C libraries, I think it won't work if you are packaging the dependencies from a Windows machine.

Comment: Yes, I used Ubuntu to create package

Comment: Ok. Just a suggestion, the guy here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66924714/eof-occurred-in-violation-of-protocol-ssl-c1125-on-python3-8-slim-buster resolved his issue by reverting to an older base of python:3.7-alpine. Does it work for you if you use Lambda Python 3.7 runtime, instead of 3.8?

Comment: Please update the question with specific versions of PyOpenSSL, Certifi and requests packages. It's also helpful to include a snippet of code of how your app is making the request